# sqlite view calculating value based on previous row

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table "data" with the following schema:

```
id  date                bw      bf
.   .                   .       .
33  2018-03-25 00:00:00 76.2    0.148
34  2018-04-01 00:00:00 75.9    0.148
35  2018-04-08 00:00:00 76.9    0.148
```

I created a view on that table with this sql statement:

```
create view eval as
select
a.*,
round(a.bw * a.bf,2) as bf_kg,
round(a.bw - b.bw,2) as d_bw,
round(a.bw * a.bf - b.bw * b.bf,2) as d_bf
from
data a
left join
data b on
a.id = b.id + 1
```

which gives me:

```
id date                 bw      bf      bf_kg    d_bw  b_bf
0   2017-07-16 00:00:00 77.9    0.221   17.22    NULL  NULL
.   .                   .       .       .        .      .
33  2018-03-25 00:00:00 76.2    0.148   11.28    0.0   0.0
34  2018-04-01 00:00:00 75.9    0.148   11.23   -0.3  -0.04
35  2018-04-08 00:00:00 76.9    0.148   11.38    1.0   0.15
.   .                   .       .       .        .      .
37  2017-04-12 00:00:00 80.0    0.148   11.84   14.0   2.07
```

**Question:**

While the view works as expected there is one caveat.

*I've to make sure that data cannot be entered before an already entered date.*

I'd like to mitigate that so that the initial order of the data doesn't matter and only the view orders the data based on the date to calculate the correct values based on the 'previous' entry.
Id 37 should be the first 'entry' in the view based on date and id 0 shouldn't have *null* values.

How can I accomplish that? I probably can't use the id so the only way would be a join on the date as in:

```
 a.date = b.date
```

but then I loose the rolling window over the previous entry because I can't do:

```
 a.date = b.date + 1
```

or something similar, or can I?

Comment: There is no order in a view/table other than what you impose via `ORDER BY`.  As for preventing the entering of invalid dates, this also doesn't really have anything to do with the view.  Can you clarify what you are trying to do here?

Comment: I'm using the view to calculate values based on the current row and previous row. Right now this 'previous' row is joined on the id column. Since there is no order but the calculations has to be based on current date / previous date I'm stuck on how to accomplish that